# Link a TFS Build Definition (CI) to a TFS Pull Request

Tags: tfs

I am reading the instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-status?view=azure-devops#status-policy.
I have a TFS Build Definition which executes tests for every branch and reports success/failure.

I'd like to link the corresponding build to the Pull Request as well (and make require a green status to merge, if possible), similar to the screenshot below.

How can I do that, do I edit the repo Policies or in some other way? The link doesn't give much detail on how to do the actual linking.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your repo -> branches -> select the branch that will be the target for your PullRequests -> Open the context menu left to the commit-id -> "Branch policies".

There you define your criteria for pull requests and can add a build under "Build validation".